# handlebars #each array is helper

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I have a helper that returns requested array.  I want to use an each to iterate the array returned by the helper.  Any way to get this to work?

imagine the handlebars helper returns this array

```
names: [{
     firstname: "first1",
     lastname: "last1"
},{
     firstname: "first2",
     lastname: "last2"
}]
```

My handlebars code would looks something like this

```
{{#each myhelpername "keyword passed to helper"}}
<p>Hi {{firstname}} {{lastname}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your helper is already returning an array why do you need to use `#each` again.

The `firstName` and `lastName` should be part of each item which is returned. So your template would look something in these lines.

```
{{#myhelpername "keyword passed to helper"}}
    <p>Hi {{firstname}} {{lastname}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

If you need to iterate over the helper using an `each` wrap it inside `()`

```
{{#each (myhelpername "something something")}} 
    <p>Hi {{firstname}} {{lastname}}</p>
 {{/each}}
```

Comment: I did get it working, thanks for the reply, I did have to tweek it though.  I had to wrap my helper in () and keep the `#each ` or it would not work.  If you edit your answer, I will mark it as answered.

`{{#each (myhelpername "something something")}}
    <p>Hi {{firstname}} {{lastname}}</p>
{{/each}}`

Comment: @bigt11 Glad it worked out for you. You can also tweak your original helper for it to return a list instead of a single item.